# tcl script not able to read a element from array?

Tags: tcl

I am taking an array and printing its values using tcl scripts but when I run the script is says
 `can't read "ipname(0)": no such element in array`

Here is the code I am using

```
array set ipname {UART TEST SPI I2C}
set asize 4
for {set i 0} {$i < $asize} {incr i}  {
      puts "$ipname($i) "
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `array set` command doesn't do what you think. Essentially, it is as if you defined it as follows:

```
ipname("UART") = "TEST"
ipname("SPI") = "I2C"
```

What you want is

```
set ipname(0) "UART"
set ipname(1) "TEST"
set ipname(2) "SPI"
set ipname(3) "I2C"
```

or

```
array set ipname {0 UART 1 TEST 2 SPI 3 I2C}
```

See the documentation for Tcl arrays: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/array.htm